# Vite/React project Npm run dev doesnt work

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, vite

I'm trying Npm run dev in my front-end folder but there's a error

PS C:\Users\PICHAU\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\home\viceek\ProjetoI\front-end> npm run dev

> front-end@0.0.0 dev
> vite

failed to load config from C:\Users\PICHAU\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\home\viceek\ProjetoI\front-end\vite.config.ts
error when starting dev server:
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'vite' imported from C:\Users\PICHAU\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\home\viceek\ProjetoI\front-end\vite.config.ts.timestamp-1665345725237.mjs
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:393:5)
at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:860:9)
at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:909:20)
at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1124:11)
at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:837:30)
at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:18)
at ModuleWrap. (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:40)
at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:75:36)

my vite.config.ts folder:i

````
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()]
})```
````

Comment: `npm install -D vite`?

Comment: can you share your `package.json` file?

Answer (score 0):

Check out if all the dependencies are installed like react and react-dom

just run:-

> for npm

```
npm install react react-dom
```

> for yarn

```
yarn add react react-dom
```